# Clarification on finding angle between free surface and the horizontal

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, fluid-statics

I have been taught that in order to find the angle made by a liquid in a container with the horizontal, we use the fact that the free surface is perpendicular to the net force vector acting on the fluid (including the pseudo force vector for an accelerating container), however, if say the container is moving horizontally with an acceleration, this would lead to the conclusion that the free surface makes a right angle with the floor/horizontal, which is clearly wrong. Where am I going wrong? I think that I make a mistake in the "net force" part of my above statement. Please help me in clarifying my misconception. Thank you.